# System.TypeInitializationException Error when creating a Log Object | C#

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, locking

I'm creating a new project and just wrote up the following `Log` file, but am encountering an `unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occured in My_Project.exe`

The inner exception states that `{"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."}`

The error occurs when I first write to the `Log`. For example, when I use the following code, the program crashes with the error message.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using My_Project.forms;

namespace My_Project {
    public static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main() {
            Utility.MyLog.Write("Test");   //<-- ERROR OCCURS HERE
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Window());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's where the Log is being instantiated..

```
public static class Utility
{
    // DEFAULT LOG OUTPUT.
    public static Log MyLog = new Log();

    ...
}
```

Here is my `Log.cs` file, in it's entirety so far..

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using My_Project.Properties;

// STATIC USING MEMBERS
using static My_Project.LogFormat;
using static System.IO.File;
using static My_Project.Utility;

namespace My_Project {
    public enum LogFormat { None, Message, Evaluate, Process, Result }

    public sealed class Log {
        // USED TO LOCK THE OUTPUT THREAD WHEN WRITING TO A FILE.
        private readonly object _lock = new object();

        // DEFAULT VARIABLES
        public readonly string FileName;
        public readonly string FilePath;

        // DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
        public Log(string fileName = null, string filePath = null) {
            FileName = fileName ?? Resources.DefaultLogFileName;

            var directoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent;
            if (directoryInfo != null)
                filePath = Path.Combine(filePath ?? directoryInfo.FullName, Resources.DefaultLogFilePath, FileName);
            FilePath = filePath;

            var projectName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToUpper();
            Write("Hello World!");
        }

        // WRITES TO A TXT FILE, AND AUTO-CREATES A FILE IF IT DOESN'T EXIST.
        public void Write(string message) {
            lock (_lock) {
                try {
                    AppendAllText(FilePath, message);
                } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(Resources.Error_CannotFindLogFile), ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        // OPENS THE LOG FILE IN NOTEPAD.
        public void Open() => OpenProgram(FilePath);

        // CLEARS ALL CONTENTS FROM LOG.TXT.
        public void Clear() => WriteAllText(FilePath, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: This is caused by errors in initialization code for static members (either static prop/field declarations that call methods/constructors, or static constructors). In your case, the `Utility` type cannot be constructed, because in order to do so requires successfully constructing a new `Log`. The first time the `Utility` class is referenced in the code, the type initializers run (e.g. the line `public static Log MyLog = new Log();` runs) It seems like `new Log()` is throwing. Use a debugger. Find out where the issue is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was an Invalid File Path error occurring in my Resource file. I had the incorrect folder name that was being read-in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly in which line the exception is occurring since can't debug your code but you are getting the exception cause initializing `Log()` is failing somewhere either in the constructor or in the `Write()` method since inside constructor you are calling `Write("Hello World!");`. Specifically the line below. You should put a breakpoint in your `Log` class constructor and step through it and see where exactly it's failing. You already have the reason (see the inner exception message `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal`).

```
public static Log MyLog = new Log();
```

Comment: The error is occurring in the Main() function of the project, as listed above, and is occurring whenever  `Utility.MyLog.Write("Test");   //<-- ERROR OCCURS HERE` is called. It crashes on this line completely, and doesn't actually flow into the Log.cs class.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus, no it does flow. Read the answer properly and put a breakpoint and debug through the code and see exactly where it fails. that's what can say at this point.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It's crashing on the call of the object, and not allowing me to debug into the `Log.cs` class. I've been trying to debug the code the entire time.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus, you really didn't read the answer properly. well put a  breakpoint in your Log class constructor and in Write method and once breakpoint hits press F11.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's the line that has `string.Format(Resources.Error_CannotFindLogFile)`. The format is unnecessary since WriteLine does it for you.

Comment: Nah, still receiving the same error after the change.